# Surjective Function From Powerset To Set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a  surjective function with a domain a powerset of a set Σ and codomain that set Σ?
$$f: 2^{\Sigma} \rightarrow \Sigma$$
Like the "opposite" of Cantor's theorem in terms of domain and codomain.

Comment: Well, not if $\Sigma$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\Sigma$ is nonempty. Take $f(\{a\})=a$ for singleton inputs and map every other input to some arbitrary element.

I am not sure why this is the "opposite" of Cantor's theorem.